# Python.h file not found error after reinstalling using apt-get install python3-dev

Tags: python, cmake

```
/SPlisHSPlasH/extern/pybind/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:112:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

#include <Python.h>

I keep getting this CMake error even after running the sudo apt-get install the dev tools and all the other proposed solutions in the previous answers. After I cmake.. I do make and keep getting the Python.h error.

Comment: I think that `Python.h` resides in `/usr/include/python3.6` or whatever (rather than `/usr/include`), so you may need to ensure that the compilation has the right `-I` option to pick up the relevant include directory. Though how you achieve that with `cmake` I couldn't tell you.

Comment: thanks a ton, I had overlooked that detail. I just changes the include path to add the python m3.6 and it worked great. Downside is that I had to do it for 3 others similar issues